# Getting java.util.NoSuchElementException with Iterator.next() while using the libphonenumber

Tags: java, android

code :

```
 public void  extractPhoneNumber(String input){

        Iterator<PhoneNumberMatch> existsPhone= PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().findNumbers(input, "IN").iterator();

        while (existsPhone.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("Phone == " + existsPhone.next().number());
            Log.d("existsPhone",":"+existsPhone.next().rawString());

            gotPhone.setText(existsPhone.next().rawString());

        }
    }
```

Log :

```
2019-06-11 16:23:43.059 11176-11176/com.example.cardscaning E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cardscaning, PID: 11176
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cardscaning/com.example.cardscaning.Activity.ProcessImage}: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
     Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher.next(PhoneNumberMatcher.java:710)
        at com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher.next(PhoneNumberMatcher.java:43)
        at com.example.cardscaning.Activity.ProcessImage.extractPhoneNumber(ProcessImage.java:291)
        at com.example.cardscaning.Activity.ProcessImage.onCreate(ProcessImage.java:97)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6687)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2631)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2743) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1490) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

Inside log I can get desire result but exception occurs when I am adding this line `gotPhone.setText(existsPhone.next().rawString())`

Desirable outcome is able use extracted number.

Comment: from where you are calling `extractPhoneNumber` ? It may have reference to view item but the activity is not initialized yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `next()` **thrice** in one iteration forcing the Iterator to move to an element that doesn't exist.

Instead of:

```
while (existsPhone.hasNext()){
     System.out.println("Phone == " + existsPhone.next().number());
     Log.d("existsPhone",":"+existsPhone.next().rawString());
     //...
}
```

Use something like:

```
while (existsPhone.hasNext()){
   PhoneNumberMatch phone = existsPhone.next();

   System.out.println("Phone == " + phone.number());
   Log.d("existsPhone",":"+phone.rawString());
   //....
}
```